# Linking of MeSH terms and genes

Tags: gene

Is there an alternative to mesh2gene for linking MeSH terms to genes?

The http://www.ncibi.org/gene2mesh.html site appears to be down for months now (click on "Launch Gene2MeSH via gene2mesh.ncibi.org") and I've been unable to find an alternative so far...

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use the [MESH.db](https://doi.org/doi:10.18129/B9.bioc.MeSH.db) package in Bioconductor to annotate your genes. I have never used, but you should be able to do something like:

```
library("MeSH.db")
select(MeSH.db, keys = myGenes, keytype = "ENTREZ", columns = "MESH")
```

It depends on the [MeSHDbi](https://doi.org/doi:10.18129/B9.bioc.MeSHDbi) package from which you could retrieve other data form that database if needed